# Performance of compiling a expression

Tags: c#, generics, func

I have the following method and curious about performance impact of compiling Expression.

```
    public async Task<Response<TResult>> Execute<TApi, TResult>(Expression<Func<TApi, Task<TResult>>> executeApiMethod)
    { 
        try
        {
            var responseData = await executeApiMethod.Compile()(restApi).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new Response<TResult>(responseData);
        }
        catch (ApiException refitApiException)
        {


            throw;
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way? Is there any performance impact of `compile()`, since this is generic and may be called with different arguments each time running compile is scavy.

Comment: I would expect it at least partly to depend on the expressions you're compiling. It's entirely reasonable to be wary of it - but the right next step is to *measure* the impact on performance. We don't know enough about your application to know what would be reasonable and what would be too high, or whether there are caching opportunities etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet my use case is wrapping api calls to handle error situations. ie: `clienthandler.execute(a=>a.GetSomething(), myApiContract)` so that I dont have to repeat the same code everywhere.

Comment: Why are you using expression trees for that instead of just a normal delegate though? (I assume that your error handling code is actually more complex - just catching and rethrowing is pointless.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I removed the code for brevety. You mean I should use Func instead of Expression?

Comment: Well it certainly *looks* like you'd be able to just use `Func`, yes.